# FastAPI - HTTP Basic Auth - Choose own usernam/pass & Base64

Tags: python, fastapi

**How can I add my username and password and add a base64 for Basic Auth. (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/http-basic-auth/)**

I have read quite bit and I ended up even to setup *OAuth2 with Password (and hashing), Bearer with JWT tokens* but that ended up to be too much for me and all I need is only a simple Basic Auth and to add a small protection on it, basically add a base64.

The idea was to have something like this in header:

`{'Authorization': 'Basic aGVsbG86d29ybGQ='} #hello:world`

However my knowledge is pretty low and I am having the first issue with even configure on how to use my own username and password with:

```
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
from fastapi.security import HTTPBasic, HTTPBasicCredentials

app = FastAPI()

security = HTTPBasic()


@app.get("/users/me")
def read_current_user(credentials: HTTPBasicCredentials = Depends(security)):
    return {"username": credentials.username, "password": credentials.password}
```

[image: The Sign IN]

#### My question:

How can I choose my own username and password and after that be ablet o use base64 to encode/decode the Authorization to be able to send to header something like:

`{'Authorization': 'Basic aGVsbG86d29ybGQ='} #hello:world`

Comment: you know that Basic Authentication is actually a really bad option for authentication, right? Everyone could read the username/password header and decode it (it is base64 encoded)

Comment: I know that and probably I won't do anything big project - enough big to "care" if its being hacked or not since it won't affect anything I do. :D @t_e_o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't worked with FastAPI, but I took a look at the docs. You have the following source code provided there:

```
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, HTTPException
from fastapi.security import HTTPBasic, HTTPBasicCredentials
from starlette.status import HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED

app = FastAPI()

security = HTTPBasic()


def get_current_username(credentials: HTTPBasicCredentials = Depends(security)):
    if credentials.username != "foo" or credentials.password != "password":
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect email or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Basic"},
        )
    return credentials.username


@app.get("/users/me")
def read_current_user(username: str = Depends(get_current_username)):
    return {"username": username}
```

So what you have to do is to use a `Depends` object. This hier is a simple example, but usually your `get_current_username()` would do a database query to check if the user and their corresponding password exist.
You can also take a look at this git-repo https://gist.github.com/nilsdebruin/8b36cd98c9949a1a87e3a582f70146f1

I hope this helps you! :)

Comment: Hey again! So basically that's te part that I don't understand about how I can be able to edit it so I can change the username and password that I wish to use. Because right now  I don't managed to get it to work at all. The code works but I don't know what username and password I have currently with that code :(

Comment: your username is "foo" ,and the pass is "password"

Comment: Just take a look at the get_current_username() function - it makes a check if the username and password correspond to the hard-coded strings

Comment: Thats the strange part. When entering foo and password into the input field. It sends me back as incorrect email or pass even though I write foo password

Comment: It happens when I enter the swagger like the picture I have at the top. It comes a popout that ask for username and password

Comment: can you put some kind of a print() statement in the get_current_username() method? Just print out the username and the pass

Comment: Will check later on. But thats a good way to see. I didn't thought about it :)

Comment: You should not do that direct pythonic comparison. You can find details in FastAPI's doc: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59388336/fastapi-http-basic-auth-choose-own-usernam-pass-base64